# How to increase the size of black square using unicode? C++

Tags: unicode, cout

i am making chess and i used this code to insert white blocks

```
        for(column=8;column>=1; column--)
         {if ( column%2 == 0)
           {
     
              cout<<(char)254u<<"\t\t" ;
          }
```

what i want to know is how to increase size of the white squares, also i'm planning to insert black squares instead of \t\t, is cout the right thing to use here?

Answer (score 1):

To increase the size of the squares, which are characters just like regular letters, you will need to increase the font size of the terminal in which you display it.

Comment: but wouldn't that increase the size of everything else as well? i just want the squares to be bigger not the rest of the text

Comment: I don't think it's possible, assuming a regular bash terminal, to increase the size of certain characters in a line, but not others. Not without resorting to a library like ncurses, which will allow you to create more types of graphics inside a terminal.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are making this as a console app, and not a GUI app?